# Editing questions/answers for capitalization, etc

Tags: discussion, editing

What should the guide be for editing a question or answer in relation to capitalizing `He` (in reference to God), `God`, `Bible`, etc... where most Biblical texts captilize them?

Since this is a place for non-Christians to come to find answers in addition to 'expert' Christians, I am not sure if their input should be edited for that difference or not.

Comment: [What is the generally accepted term for X?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/342/352#352)

Comment: Also, this point in the above question is specifically on capitalization: [What is the generally accepted term for X?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/342/352#352)

Answer (score 10):

Proper nouns are proper nouns. I think that ultimately, these should be fixed in the same manner as addressing any other form of capitalization that is needed when dealing with someone who is unfamiliar with the given material. I think it's fair that we can treat these no less than we treat any other form of capitalization fixes.

In general, capitalization falls under the same point as spelling and punctuation - don't go out of your way especially if there isn't a lot to fix. If there's a lot to be fixed in the post, or if there is a particularly egregious issue that must be fixed, then it is probably more warranted to step in with editing.

If there is only one or two instances in the post, and nothing else to fix, it may be helpful to make a *polite and helpful* nudge in the comments, reminding the author that it is a proper noun.

Comment: Except that He isn't a proper noun, and in some Christian circles (and some languages), if you are referring to God you also capitalize the He, His, Him...

Answer (score -1):

I don't think we should be editing other people's posts to capitalize he to He. I *do* think that we should capitalize god, if it's talking about one God, and not gods in general. I think that Bible should be capitalized too, after all that's its name.

However, what we **shouldn't** be doing is Having All Caps Question Titles (I've seen some).

I'd definitely edit those down.